# How is chamar-se used?

Tags: conjugações

I think "chamar-se" means "being called".

Are the following example sentences correct?

- Eu chamar-me Martin. (I call myself Martin.)
- Você chamar-se Martin. (You call yourself Martin.)
- Ele chamar-se Martin. (He calls himself Martin.)
- Ela chamar-se Anna. (She calls herself Anna.)
- Nós chamamo-nos Anna e Martin. (We call ourselves Anna and Martin.)
- Vós  chamais-vos Anna e Martin. (You call yourselves Anna and Martin.)
- Eles chamam-se Anna e Martin. (They call themselves Anna and Martin.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "chamar" is to call.

In this case, it's [the pronominal form of "chamar"](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/chamar), which means "to be called".

## Sample sentences

Your sample sentences are almost correct.
You forgot to [conjugate](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/Conjugar/chamar) the verbs on the first 4 examples.

> - eu chamo(-me)
> - tu chamas(-te)
> - ele chama(-se)
> - nós chamamos (chamamo-nos
> - (vós chamais(-vos))
> - eles chamam(-se)

So:

- Eu cha**mo**-me Martin.
- Você cha**ma**-se Martin.
- Ele cha**ma**-se Martin.
- Ela cha**ma**-se Anna.
- Nós chamamo-nos Anna e Martin.
- Vós chamais-vos Anna e Martin.
- Eles chamam-se Anna e Martin.

## Vós is not normally used

I'd like to point out that the conjugation of the 2nd person plural, **vós**, is not much used these days.
Instead, we use "vocês" with the third person plural: "**vocês chamam-se Anna e Martin.**"

This question will clarify: [Why is "vós" rarely used today?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/390/why-is-v%C3%B3s-rarely-used-today)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that while, word by word, *eu chamo-me Martin* means *I call myself Martin*, we don't think that way: it's just a way of saying *my name is Martin*; nobody thinks of Martin actually calling himself. Compare with *Martin fez um disparate e chamou-se os piores nomes* (or better, *chamou a si mesmo os piores nomes*) Here Martin actually calls himeself names.

Comment: Note: in Brazil, it's much more common to use proclitic pronoums, such as in *Eu **me** chamo Martin*. Actually, in spoken language it's frequently ommited: *Eu chamo Martin*.