# O uso incorreto da palavra "tava" com sentido de "estava"

Tags: significado, ortografia

É comum ouvirmos aqui no Brasil, pelo menos no interior de Minas Gerais onde eu moro, a palavra "tava" com sentido de "estava".

Vi que existem algumas músicas com essa palavra:

(1) Na música Desenho de Deus de Armandinho:

> Quando Deus te desenhou, ele **tava** namorando
>   Quando Deus te desenhou, ele **tava** namorando
>   Na beira do mar, na beira do mar do amor
>   Na beira do mar, na beira do mar do amor
>   Papai do céu na hora de fazer você[...]
>   Fonte: https://www.vagalume.com.br/armandinho/desenho-de-deus.html

Obs: o compositor arrumou até namorada para Deus...

(2) Na música Farinhada de Zé Dantas contada por Luiz Gonzaga e Elba Ramalho:

> **Tava** na peneira eu **tava** peneirando
>   Eu tava num namoro eu tava namorando
>   Na farinhada lá da Serra do Teixeira
>   Namorei uma cabôca nunca vi tão feiticeira[...]
>   Fonte: https://www.letras.mus.br/elba-ramalho/767581/

É aceitável esse tipo de erro na língua coloquial falada?

Comment: "A chave tava com quem? em algumas construções talvez para evitar a chiadeira come-se o 'es'

Comment: Denis Caixeta e @AndréLyra em Portugal usa-me muito o *tava*, eu uso quase todos os dias, falado e escrito informalmente. Mas, formalmente é sempre estava.

Comment: Mas a pergunta foi sobre 'língua coloquial falada'.

Comment: Na linguagem coloquial falada, o que é um erro?

Comment: @eightShirt Há muitas construções que são "erradas" (isto é, inaceitáveis) no coloquial. Exemplos: As casa é azuis. O viaduto desabamos. A reta rua é. Não vos chamei por que não estáveis ainda prontos. (Sim, essa última é aceitável no padrão, mas não no coloquial, a não ser num contexto de galhofa).

Comment: @LuísHenrique essa discussão é muito ampla. No meu ponto de vista, nada disso é inaceitável no coloquial, onde predominam espontaneidade e informalidade, bem como não há, necessariamente, preocupação com a gramática normativa, ao contrário da língua culta. De acordo com o professor Vicente Santos, "[...] nada é errado nem certo, ninguém fala bonito ou feio, fala diferente". Se um grupo fala "As casa é azuis" e se entende, quem somos para dizer que isso é inaceitável? A discussão é bem interessante :-)

Comment: @eightShirt - Porém não é assim que o registro coloquial funciona. Ele tem regras, às vezes bem rígidas, às vezes até mais rígidas do que as do padrão; elas apenas não foram codificadas num *corpus* normativo. E uma das regras do português coloquial é uma hierarquia do que vai para o plural. O predicativo do sujeito só vai para o plural se o verbo também for; assim "As casa são azul" é aceitável, "As casa é azuis" não é, embora inteligível. Da mesma forma, aceita-se "tu foi", mas não "você foste". É só usar essas expressões em conversa coloquial, para verificar que os falantes as estranham.

Comment: @LuísHenrique O funcionamento de qualquer registro coloquial, seja ele qual for, não impede que um grupo use qualquer uma das construções que consideras inaceitáveis. Assim como o professor Vicente Santos e outros pesquisadores, Ataliba Teixeira de Castilho diz que, "cientificamente, só é errado quando você fala e o outro não entende". Por esta tese, se uma mensagem for compreendida, não estaria configurado um erro.

Comment: Acredito que isso dependa do grupo onde se dá a comunicação, e mantenho o questionamento: se um grupo fala "as casa é azuis" e se entende, quem somos para dizer que isso é inaceitável? A propósito, você poderia citar os autores nos quais se baseia? Gostaria de ter o registro daqueles que contra-argumentam.

Comment: Creio que meu posicionamento é semelhante ao do Mario Alberto Perini, por exemplo em *Gramática do Português Brasileiro*. A língua coloquial e a língua popular não se caracterizam pela ausência de regras, mas por regras diferentes das do padrão. O "inaceitável" não se reduz ao ininteligível, mas é aquilo que o falante/ouvinte rejeita como "não sendo parte da língua", e é evidentemente contextual. Ainda que você consiga entender o discurso de um estrangeiro que não sabe o gênero das palavras em português, você sabe que "*o meu mãe*" não é português.

Comment: Uma breve nota, @LuísHenrique : numa região grande do nordeste de Portugal (eu diria que em todo o Trás-os-Montes e Alto Douro), [ainda se usa a segunda pessoa do plural](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/390/why-is-v%c3%b3s-rarely-used-today); «Não vos chamei por que não estáveis ainda prontos.» seria por lá uma frase perfeitamente aceitável e comum, tanto no registo escrito como no registo falado, e tanto no registo informal como no registo formal.

Comment: @ANeves - Evidentemente, o coloquial é geograficamente mais variado do que o padrão. Daí ser difícil generalizar - o que é aceitável no coloquial do interior do Rio Grande do Sul pode não ser em Salvador, ou no Faro, ou em Braga. Neste sentido, minhas observações se referem - e se restringem - ao coloquial urbano brasileiro. Mas... diz-se também "*táveis*" por "*estáveis*"? :-)

Comment: @LuísHenrique atenção que lá o vós tanto é usado coloquial como formalmente. E sim, em discurso coloquial dizem por exemplo "vós tais é malucos, se achais qu'o Portimonense não desce de divisão este ano..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa forma (bem como toda uma conjugação paralela do verbo estar, "tou", "tás", "tive", "tiveste", "tavam", "tamos", "taria", "tando") é inaceitável no padrão, mas completamente aceitável (e até preferível, eu diria) no coloquial (registro no qual, portanto, não constitui um "erro"). O mesmo vale para o registro popular, de que é exemplo a tua segunda citação.

Comment: Por que o *downvote*?

Comment: não chega nunca a ser preferível; é somente algo não reprovável na maioria dos casos