# Qual é a etiqueta no uso de «vós podeis, vós sabeis», etc. no norte de Portugal?

Tags: pronomes, regionalismo, informalidade, vós

O tratamento por ***vós*** com conjugação dos verbos na segunda pessoa do plural, *vós podeis, vós sabeis*, etc, sobrevive no norte de Portugal. A minha questão é se esse tratamento denota a mesma familiaridade que o tratamento por ***tu*** ou ***vocês***, ou se é bem-visto usá-lo em vez de *os senhores*.

Por exemplo, se eu me dirigisse a um grupo de desconhecidos já com cabelos brancos, seria rude se perguntasse:

> Podeis indicar-me o caminho para a Sé?

Em que circunstâncias é que é bem-visto usar-se o *vós* em vez de *os senhores*? Faz diferença se omitirmos o pronome, como no exemplo acima?

Comment: Para mim, que sou brasileiro, isso sempre foi uma dificuldade Qual o pronome que expressa mais intimidade e informalidade em Portugal: tu ou você?  Como devo dirigir-me (também em Portugal) aos "desonhecidos já com cabelos brancos",  vós ou os senhores?  No Brasil usar "tu" ou "você" com adultos desconhecidos, principalmente os mais velhos, frequentemente é visto como pouca educação.  Usamos "o(s) senhor(es) ou a(s) senhora(s).  O pronome pessoal "vós"  é dificilmente usado no português padrão por aqui.  Usar "vós" rotineiramente dará a certeza de que tu acabaste de chegar do século XIX.

Comment: Eu respondi aqui: [Why is “vós” rarely used today?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/390/why-is-v%C3%B3s-rarely-used-today/1363#1363) (repara que o título da pergunta e o corpo da mesma não batem certo; respondi aos dois)

Comment: @Centaurus: *Vós* é usado só no norte de Portugal. A fronteira entre *você(s)* e *o(s) senhore(s)* creio que é mais ou menos a mesma em Portugal e no Brasil. Já foi tocado [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/205/when-to-use-o-senhor) e [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/514/when-to-use-tua-and-sua). Em Portugal, *tu* é familiar/informal, e *você* fica algures  entre *tu* e *o senhor*, num espaço cada vez mais apertado e arriscado. Mas tu podes falar aqui como no Brasil. Desde que mantenhas o sotaque brasileiro não terás problemas.

Comment: @Artefacto: Não me lembrava da totalidade da tua resposta. Ela responde cabalmente à minha pergunta, apesar de a outra pergunta ser só sobre a razão de *vós* ter caído em desuso. (Copa e corpo estão de acordo; tu respondes é também à outra resposta que afirma que *vós* é formal). Para já vou manter esta pergunta. A outra pergunta é de facto diferente, e eu gostaria de ter alguma resposta de alguém que use ou tenha contacto direto com o uso de *vós*.

Comment: @JacintoHmm tens razão, simplesmente a resposta do OP é que fala sobre as situações em que é usado.

Comment: Jacinto, alguém que trabalha comigo usa "vós" simplesmente em vez de "vocês" (informal, "tu" para a primeira pessoa). Essa pessoa é transmontana. É uma coisa costumeira, para aqueles lados. Mas não sei se "vós" pode ser usado formalmente.

Comment: @ANeves Então o *vós* já não se usa no Porto? Tens que convencer esse teu colega a vir aqui responder a esta pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aqui na zona do Minho, tanto usamos **vós** como **vocês**.

O exemplo que deste é um caso especial, visto que, se usa quase sempre com pessoas desconhecidas e raramente se usa o *vós podeis*, em  vez disso usa-se o *vocês podem* se for gente mais nova.

Se nos estamos a dirigir a um(s) "desconhecido(s) já com cabelos brancos" usamos **sempre** "O(s) Senhor(es)".

Claro que, se for usado como no teu exemplo, o **vós** vai dar a ideia que estás a falar com um Rei e que vieste diretamente do século XIX, como disse o Centaurus, dependendo da forma como falas,

> "Vós podeis-me dar licença?" - pergunto eu.
>
> "Sim, diga jovem." - respondem os senhores.
>
> "Vós saberíeis-me dizer o caminho para a Sé de Braga?"

Mas se o uso do **vós** não for tão formal pode parecer confiança a mais com os ditos senhores.

---

Na aldeia onde nasci, [Telhado](https://www.google.pt/maps/place/4770+Telhado/@41.4545483,-8.4717108,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xd24f82680dad77d:0xf76f82967c8430ba), costuma-se usar duma forma mais informal,

> (Vós) quereis ir à zona da Sé beber um café?

Se estiverem a falar com pessoas desconhecidas mais novas ou conhecidas e mais velhas usa-se,

> (Vocês) querem ir à zona da Sé beber um café?

Já na cidade onde moro há 10 anos, [Braga](https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Braga/@41.5404453,-8.4808175,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0xd24feb0f0dd4701:0x400ebbde4902f90), entre as pessoas mais novas usa-se mais **vocês** formal e informalmente. Talvez por ser uma cidade Universitária, não sei. O que é certo é que eu comecei a falar um português mais "nacional" quando vim estudar para Braga em 2003, até então, falava com mais sotaque e com certas variações que se usam mais em zonas rurais.

Mais informações: [O uso de vós, novamente](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-vos-novamente/25334)