# É correto usarmos a segunda pessoa do plural quando nos dirigimos a uma só pessoa? Por quê?

Tags: pronomes

A segunda pessoa do plural, vós, é supostamente o plural de tu. Contudo já foi muito usada no passado quando alguém se dirigia a uma só pessoa. Ainda percebo o seu uso em pt-BR em certos contextos como ocorre no Legislativo, no Judiciário e em preces. Esse uso é correto?  Por quê?

Comment: Parece-me que a questão é: por qual razão se utiliza o pronome da segunda pessoa do plural para se referir a uma pessoa singular. No meu entendimento, isso se deve ao fato de que quando nos dirigimos a pessoas dentro do universo religioso (como deuses e santos) ou dentro das relações de soberania (reis, imperadores, etc.), devemos levar em conta a necessidade de reconhecimento de que o interlocutor, digno das mais altas reverências, reúne mais poderes que o de uma pessoa só. No caso do nosso Deus cristão, por exemplo, é espírito, mas também se fez alma e corpo, em três, portanto, plural. cont.

Comment: [_continuação do comentário do Lucio_] A mesma conjectura se poderia fazer em relação a reis e imperadores, porque reunidos neles se encontram poderes múltiplos, plurais. Ao nos dirigirmos a eles e utilizarmos os pronomes da segunda pessoa do plural, estamos a reconhecer a sua idoneidade como os sujeitos de múltiplos poderes que são. Questão de fé e respeito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, o uso de vós é correto para indicar uma só pessoa.

O uso de vós é formal, tal como você (em pt-pt) ou o senhor.

Tal como notado na pergunta, o uso de vós é frequentemente usado na divindade. O mesmo pode ser constatado pela oração do [Pai Nosso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pai_Nosso)

Pode também constatar que [os livros mais recentes do google com a utilização de "vós sois"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22v%C3%B3s+sois%22&tbm=bks&tbs=sbd:1) (segunda pessoa do singular) têm temática religiosa.

O uso de vós era também usado [para tratar a realeza](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-o-tratamento-para-a-realeza/30225). É de lembrar que o regime monárquico [acabou em 1910 em Portugal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarquia_de_Portugal) e [no fim da década de 1880 no Brasil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proclama%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_Rep%C3%BAblica_do_Brasil). Este poderia ter sido um dos motivos que levaria á diminuição do uso de vós em favor de você, ou o senhor, ou [outros pronomes de tratamento mais usados na escrita](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf46.php).

Contudo [o google trends mostra que na verdade ele tem vindo a aumentar](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore?date=all&q=v%C3%B3s), embora não seja possível verificar se tem vindo a aumentar também para a segunda pessoa do singular. [Contudo esta subida não é relevante quando comparada com você, ou o senhor](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore?date=all&q=v%C3%B3s,o%20senhor,voc%C3%AA).

Comment: *"formal, tal como você ou senhor"*  é bom explicar que no Brasil "você" indica intimidade, não sendo nem um pouco formal.  *"se tem vindo a aumentar também para a primeira pessoa do singular"*   acho que você quis dizer "segunda pessoa do singular", não ?

Comment: O uso de *vós* para tratar a realeza foi substituído há séculos por outras formas, nomeadamente o *Vossa Mercê* que depois deu origem ao *você*. N'*Os Gatos* de Fialho de Almeida de 1889-1892, que ando a ler, o autor refere-se à realeza por Sua Majestade e Sua Alteza.

Comment: Mas não foi respondido por que é conjugado no plural apesar de referir-se a apenas uma pessoa.

Comment: Pelo menos na minha parte do Brasil, isto é, RJ e SP, *você* é neutro, pode ser usado em contextos informais e formais (com os devidos cuidados), longe de indicar intimidade; indicativo de intimidade seria usar gírias, como *cara* e *mano*.

Answer (score -2):

Sim. É um termo muito comum hoje em dia, apesar de que o sujeito *vos* não é muito usado hoje em dia. Mas *vos* pode ser usado quando você se refere a uma, duas ou mais pessoas, veja esses exemplos:

> Vos estamos esperando aqui por 20 minutos.
>
> O que vos deseja fazer?

Comment: Davyd, acho que você não foi muito feliz na resposta e menos ainda nos exemplos.   O que seria "um termo muito comum hoje em dia"?  "vós"?

Comment: É muito comum mas não é muito usado ?   Não entendi.   Do ponto de vista gramatical os exemplos não são bons.  O primeiro começa a frase por um pronome oblíquo, o que já não é recomendado na norma culta.  E a pergunta não é sobre pronome oblíquo, mas sim pronome reto.  O segundo exemplo tem erro de concordância.

Comment: "Acho que você não foi muito 'feliz'" ? Você quis dizer: direto ou explicativo? De qualquer forma, quando eu disse que não sâo usados recentemente, me referi ao _vos_, ninguém usa esse pronome hoje em dia, se quer realmente falar Português, nâo se apegue ao _vos_. E quando disse que eles sâo  comuns, me referi ao uso do _vos_ no singular e plural, sempre que este pronome é usado (raramente) pode ser usado para se referir a uma ou mais pessoas.

Comment: "Os dois exemplos nâo foram diretos" como assim, amigo? Os meus dois exemplos foram dois diferentes usos, nâo os usei na mesma frase, mas sim em diferentes contextos. Veja: Vos estamos esperando aqui por 20 minutos, onde vos estavas? -  Eu estava dormindo.  Finalmente é seu aniversário, o que vos desejas fazer?

Comment: Lembre-se que a conjulgação do verbo também muda quando "vos" é ultilizado, você pode escolher entre: _vos desejais fazer_ e _vos desejas fazer_. Não se apegue muito ao pronome _vos_, qual está quase extinto, hoje em dia apenas _você/s_  e  _tu_ são usados.

Comment: Talvez esteja confundindo com pronomes de tratamento usados em cartas oficiais? Mesmos estes estão sendo menos exigidos pois muitos já passaram a utilizar apenas o tratamento senhor/senhora.

Comment: Mesmo em pronomes usados em cartas formais, não é apenas senhor/senhora, e sim: _Vossa senhoria_. De qualquer forma, não são mais usados, e quando são, podem indicar o singular e plural, mas como eu disse anteriormente, se apegar a estes pronomes não será muito beneficente, uma vez que já estão quase extintos.

Comment: Davyd, o primeiro exemplo desta resposta não é relevante, porque não fala de "vós" (eu tu ele nós vós eles - pronomes retos) que é perguntado, mas de "vos" (me te lhe nos vos lhes - pronome oblíquo). O segundo exemplo parece irrelevante porque tem um forte erro gramatical de concordância; e só ficaria tanto correto *mantendo* a palavra vós, se fosse alterado para uma [forma que só parece ser usada nalgumas regiões de Portugal](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1659): "o que é que vós desejais fazer?"

Comment: Aneves, lembrando que os dois exemplos são separados, os dois não estão alocados no mesmo exemplo, eu dei 2 diferentes exemplos.
E na questão do "vos" o verbo também muda, tem a forma para cada verbo se for procedido de "vos", como por exemplo o que você citou: vos desejais, vos fazeis.. Mas hoje em dia é opcional, tanto isso quanto a forma do vos que é quase extinta.

Comment: @DavydDiniz - Não há nada opcional na conjugação dos verbos na segunda pessoa do plural. Não se diz nem se escreve "vós deseja" nem "vós estavas". Hoje em dia "vós" é desusado no Brasil e na maior parte de Portugal (e, portanto, não é muito comum). Onde ainda se usa, flexiona-se corretamente (e, se porventura deixar de ser conjugado no paradigma antigo, certamente se passará a usar o verbo na terceira pessoa do singular, não na segunda).